# Slider doesn't load when hidden div appears / shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm working with Joomla 2.5 and am using this here:
http://www.code7.co.uk/joomla-responsive-slider

My theme is a single-pager. If I click on a navigation item javascript simple fades out one div and fades in the other div. The problem now is that if I toggle the divs, the slider isn't enabled anymore. Only when I reload the page.

The Slider is loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",           
        directionNav: false,             
          controlNav:false,           
          keyboardNav:false,         
          direction: "horizontal",        
          slideshowSpeed:3000,       
          animationSpeed:600,        
          randomize: false     
        });
  });
</script>
```

It is loaded **each time** below the slider div container. I already tried to remove the code from the modules and only load the slider once. It worked, but not if I toggled the divs.

**Question: How can I "reload" the slider, when I toggle the div? I tried with .reload() the window, but then the whole fadein and out animation is worth nothing and I want to keep it!**

This is how I change:

```
function changeSection(section) {
    if(activeSection != section) {
        $('#'+activeSection).fadeToggle("slow");
        $('#'+section).delay(500).fadeToggle("slow");

        $('#menu-'+activeSection).removeClass('active');
        $('#menu-'+section).addClass('active');

        document.title = activeSectionTitle;
        history.pushState({}, '', section);

        activeSection = section;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note Not tried `Slider` piece. If possible, post `html`, `css`. Tried with substituting `jQuery(window).load(function(){})` for `$(document).ready(function(){})` ? Also, tried placing `Slider` piece in `(function($){})(jQuery)` ?

Comment: What do you mean with substituting?

Answer (score 0):

Try (updated)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:not(:first)").hide(0);
    var toggletwo = function (i) {
        $("div:not(:nth-of-type(" + i + "))").fadeOut(125, function () {
            $(this).siblings("div").fadeIn(250)
        })
    };
    $("li a").on("click", function (e) {
        return ($(e.target).is("a:first") ? toggletwo(1) : toggletwo(2))   
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/68k7F/

Comment: For all sliders at page bottom or just call it when showing the div?

Comment: @zerophreak Not certain ? `html` not posted ? Perhaps try, see if work to achieve effects. Perhaps, "wrapping" `plugin` in `(function($){})(jQuery)` may work. Again, not certain, `html` not posted, full `Slider` `plugin` pieces not posted ? If possible, create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: One simple menu <ul><li><a> etc., two <divs> - nothing else. Plus this JS // Slider like <div><ul><li><a><img>